# Message Passing Interface, MPI_Recv() method

Tags: c, mpi

I want to know the purpose of

```
MPI_Recv()
```

I am new to programming and i want to know the use of this function.

```
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank); /* find process rank */
if (myrank == 0) {
int x = 2;
MPI_Send(&x,1,MPI_INT,1,3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
} else if (myrank = = 1) {
int x;
MPI_Recv(&x,1,MPI_INT,0,3,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete function with parameters.

```
MPI Recv(void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int source, int tag,
MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Status *status)
```

The function is developed to Receive messages which are sent by the MPI(Message Passing Interface).

### Parameters

- ***buf**: receive buffer (loaded);
- ***count**: max number of entries in buer;
- ***datatype**: data type of entries;
- ***source**: source process rank (MPI_ANY_SOURCE matches with anything);
- ***tag**: message tag (MPI_ANY_TAG matches
  with anything);
- ***comm**: communicator
- ***status**: status (returned)